# Redireccionar a traves de una notificacion push

Tags: xamarin.forms, onesignal

alguien podria ayudarme, brindandome su conocimiento?
Necesito redireccionar a traves de una notificacion push a cierta vista o pantalla de mi aplicacion.
las notificaciones son con OneSignal
Agradeceria su ayuda

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y muestra el código que tienes hasta el momento. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.